# Symfony2.1 with EAV Return Values

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have three Entity:

1.Feature

2.Value

3.Product

I am getting Value In Product without mentioning It's Feature. I am trying to Get Value according to feature But But I am unable to do it.I don't Know How it can be done?

## Feature:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="feature")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Feature
{

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=50)
 */
protected $name;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Feature", mappedBy="Feature")
 **/
protected $value;

 /**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->value = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

public function __toString()
{
    return $this->getName();
}
}
```

## Value:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="value")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Value
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=50)
 */
protected $value;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Feature", inversedBy="value")
 **/
protected $feature;

 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="value")
 **/
private $product;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->feature = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

 public function __toString()
{
    return $this->getValue();
}
}
```

## Product:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Product 
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @Gedmo\Translatable
 * @ORM\Column(length=64)
 */
private $title;

/**
 * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"title"})
 * @ORM\Column(length=64, unique=true)
 */
private $slug;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
protected $quantity;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 */
protected $active;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
protected $updated;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
protected $created;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Value", inversedBy="product")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="product_value")
 **/
protected $value;


public function __construct()
{
    $this->active = true;
    $this->updated = new \DateTime();
    $this->created = new \DateTime();
    $this->value = new ArrayCollection();

}

public function __toString()
{
    return $this->getTitle();
}
}
```

I m not explaining more due to weak English .

Example What I want:

"I  want to select the feature of product for example size and color with values like red , green & small, medium etc.  as per product ."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In summary you need to build your own query:

Create a repository for Product and have something like this:

```
$qb = $this->getEntitymanager()->createQueryBuilder();
$qb
    ->select('p, f, v')
    ->from('YourBundleName:Product', 'p')
    ->leftJoin('p.value', 'v')
    ->innerJoin('v.feature', 'f');

return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Then for each product, do something like this:

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
    echo "Title: " . $product->getTitle() . "<br />";
    echo "Features: <br />";
    foreach ($product->getValue() as $value) {
        echo $value->getFeature()->getName() . ": " . $value->getValue() . "<br />"
    }
}
```